# Ruby on Rails - Navigation with Dynamic Content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navigation

Using Rails 4 (and Bootstrap with SASS if that helps). I have an `Award` model with a `:name` attribute. I would like to put in my site-wide navigation a dropdown that lists each award name with a link to their show page (about six in total). Something like...

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Awards<b class="caret"></b></a
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <% @awards.each do |award| %>
      <li><%= link_to award.name, award %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I am not used to doing something like this site-wide! What is the best way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want  site-wide navigation dropdown then looking at your code, first thing you need to do is set `@awards` which will be accessible throughout the application. In order to achieve that, add a `before_action` inside your `ApplicationController`(app/controllers/application_controller.rb).

For Example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_awards
  # .... 


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_awards
      @awards = Award.all
    end
end
```

After that you can add your view code (the one you shared in the question) in the `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file. This is your default layout file. If there is no controller-specific layout, Rails will use `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` every time.